# Resize/transform text in Sketch?

Tags: text, sketch-app

For some reason Sketch removed text resizing some time ago, but I'd say I need the feature quite often. Currently you can change text size only via size window/shortcuts which is kinda inconvenient for me.

Is there a hack to transform text layers size via dragging like in Photoshop?

Answer (score 9):

**Cmd+K** (or clicking *Scale* on the toolbar) seems to be the only option.

[image]

Comment: I really wish you could scale text by clicking and dragging the bounds of text box.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a shape of text by right clicking the text layer then select convert to outline. It will give the same resizing experience as Photoshop but you will lose editibility of text.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold Option while dragging the text bounding box, it will increase the type size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: Interesting... Are you running Mac, or PC?
You could always try CMND + K to resize (CTRL + K on PC)

Comment: Thanks! Yet still not perfect, but much more convenient than changing in the box. I'm on Mac, option is doing nothing.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. Sketch doesn't respond to Alt. It's also weird you refer a PC shortcut for Sketch. Cmd+K is cool however, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> is your only option if you want to keep text editable. You can't drag to transform/resize or use the property inspector.

The only way to scale text in a symbol is to use the scale tool <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.